# How do I change the font in a WPF RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am trying to change the font in a WPF RichTextBox using .Net Framework 4.5.2 and Visual Basic.

All of the examples such as `SelectionFont` give the error "SelectionFont is not a member of RichTextBox". Any advice on where to look would be helpful.

Comment: have u tried any code ??

Comment: The [WPF RichTextBox class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't have a `SelectionFont` property. I think you have been looking at examples that use the [Windows Forms RichTextBox class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx).

Comment: You need the `FontFamily` property.

Comment: Many thanks, I tried FontFamily, however git the wrong syntax now I have the corrent method this part is working ok

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
YourRichTextBox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontFamilyProperty, new FontFamily("Comic Sans MS"))
```

Comment: Many thanks, that did the trick, I was using the wrong format for “Selection.ApplyPropertyValue“

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the asnwer if it helped you.